# Receiving error 'E0415' when trying to return a vector

Tags: c++, function, stdvector

Trying to return a completed bubble sort after its finished from a function and I get this:

> E0415 no suitable constructor exists to convert from "std::vector<double, std::allocator<double>> *" to "std::vector<double, std::allocator<double>>"

Here's the code

```
class BubbleSort : SortingAlogrithm
{
    void swap(double *xp, double *yp)
    {
        double temp = *xp;
        *xp = *yp;
        *yp = temp;
    }
public:
    vector<double> Sort(vector<double> &newVect, int arraySize)
    {
        cout << "Bubble sort algorithm commencing" << endl;
        int i, j;
        for (i = 0; i < arraySize - 1; i++)

            // Last i elements are already in place    
            for (j = 0; j < arraySize - i - 1; j++)
                if (newVect[j] > newVect[j + 1])
                    swap(&newVect[j], &newVect[j + 1]);
        cout << "Ordered List: ";
        for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++)
        {
            cout << newVect[i] << " ";
        }
        return &newVect;
    }
};
```

Comment: Change the return statement to `return newVect` and the problem will go away.

Comment: `return &newVect;` Your function returns by value while you are trying to return by pointer.

Comment: Do you really want private inheritance?

Comment: @NeilButterworth what do you mean?

Comment: `class BubbleSort : SortingAlogrithm` is private inheritance. public inheritance is generally preferred.

Comment: @NeilButterworth Didn' realise there was a difference, I'll look into it thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
return &newVect;
```

is syntactically incorrect since the return type is `std::vector<double>` and `&newVect` is of type `std::vector<double>*`.

That's what the compiler is complaining about.

You need to use

```
return newVect;
```

#### Suggestion for improvement

It will be better to change the return type to a reference so you don't force the calling function to make a copy when they call the function.

```
vector<double>& Sort(vector<double> &newVect, int arraySize)
{
   ...
   return newVect;
}
```

It's better still to change the return type to `void` since the calling function has the object being sorted.

```
void Sort(vector<double> &newVect, int arraySize)
{
   ...
   // Not return statement
}
```

Comment: There's no need to return by reference in your example because the parameter is already passed by reference thus any change to the parameter will affect the argument.

Comment: @Raindrop7, true.

Comment: @RSahu If I was to change the return type to a void would I be able to use it in my main function? My main goal overall with this project is a program that compares how efficient different sorting algorithms are with different sets of data

Comment: @TavianT, Yes, you definitely can.

Comment: @TavianT, if you want to keep the original `std::vector` to be able to compare different sorting methods, you'll need to make copies of the original vector and pass the copies to the sorting functions.